# Obj-C - Add CLLocation values to nsdictionary?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm retrieving a list of distances with CLLocation with the following code:

**ViewController.h**

```
    @property (nonatomic) CLLocationDistance kilometers;
    @property (nonatomic) CLLocation *startLocation;
    @property (nonatomic) CLLocation *endLocation;
@property (nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary *allDistances;
```

**ViewController.m**

```
self.startLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:aPlacemark.location.coordinate.latitude longitude:aPlacemark.location.coordinate.longitude] ;


self.endLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:placemark.location.coordinate.latitude longitude:placemark.location.coordinate.latitude] ;


self.kilometers = [self.startLocation distanceFromLocation:self.endLocation] / 1000;
```

That said, I want to display the list of distances returned in my UITableView. Is it possible for me to add my returned CLLocation distances to an NSMutableDictionary (my NSMutableDictionary titled allDistances)?

Currently, if I try and display values from self.kilometers like so in a cell, I get the same value every time:

```
 [[cell kmAway] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", self.kilometers]];
```

Comment: What exactly do you want in the dictionary? You have start/end, that is 2 points on the map. So why do you need a dictionary?

Comment: I'm trying to display the calculated distance results between the current user and all other users in a tableview. All of the correct values are returned in my log, but when I attempt to display them in my tableview, I get the same value displaying in every cell :/ @battlmonstr

Comment: Please post the full source of how to you populate the users table, and where the user locations are stored, and how you calculate the current user location, and we go from there.

Comment: @Brittany you said that all correct values are returned in your log but not in tableview. how you add in array ? and how you display ? show code of that.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your distance calculations for each user are being overwritten.

I assume `allDistances` is keyed by `userID` (or something similar). Given that assumption, when the distance calculation is complete, you would want to insert that distance into `allDistances`, like so:

```c
CLLocationDistance distanceInKilometers = [self.startLocation distanceFromLocation:self.endLocation] / 1000.0;
self.allDistances[userID] = @(distanceInKilometers);
```

**NOTE**: The `@()` is necessary in order to store a primitive type (i.e. a `double`, which is what `CLLocationDistance` is) in an Objective-C collection, such as an `NSMutableDictionary`. This is called "boxing", and it turns the `CLLocationDistance` into an `NSNumber *`.

Now that all of your distances are calculated and stored within `allDistances`, in your `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, you can use them for each cell:

```c
// Assuming you know what user this cell belongs to, 
// pull the distance out of `allDistances` using their `userID`.
NSNumber *distanceNumber = self.allDistances[userID];

// "Unbox" the number as a `CLLocationDistance`
CLLocationDistance distance = distanceNumber.doubleValue;

// Use that distance to set the cell text
cell.kmAway.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", distance];
```

Comment: allDistances is not currently keyed - how can I add a key to the NSMutableDictionary, and then insert distanceInKilometers to the newly created key? I feel like this is the pivotal step I'm missing :/

Comment: If the key isn't necessary, you could alternatively insert these distances into an `NSMutableArray`, where the index in the array corresponds to the row in the table view.

Comment: A dictionary is an unordered key-value container. In order to store data in a dictionary, you must have a key. Because it's unordered, the way you retrieve that data is by passing in the key that corresponds to the value you would like to retrieve. The key can be any object that conforms to the `NSCopying` protocol. `NSString` and `NSNumber` conform to that protocol, so they can be used as a key for the dictionary.